# Runner::call: socket of context -1 is null

Tags: qt, ubuntu, qt5, squish

Squish IDE fails to run our test script. The AUT is found and starts to run but during the app init Squish outputs error. The script has worked fine before and the app runs properly when started from terminal. Qt is 5.1.1 and Squish is for that version. How to fix this issue?

```
S: AUT stderr (49820018): INFO: Loading 10 wrapper extensions from "/home/conjar/tools/squish/5.1.1/lib/extensions/qt"
S: AUT stderr (49820018): INFO: Loading Qt Wrapper configuration from "/home/conjar/tools/squish/5.1.1/etc/qtwrapper.ini"
S: AUT stderr (49820018): INFO: Loaded wrapper extension squishqtquicktypes
S: AUT stderr (49820018): INFO: Loaded wrapper extension QtWebkitExt
S: AUT stderr (49820018): INFO: Loaded wrapper extension SquishQtQuickWebViewExtension
S: AUT stderr (49820018): INFO: SquishQtDeclarative: Handling view type 'QDeclarativeView'
S: AUT stderr (49820018): INFO: SquishQtDeclarative: Support for nested QGraphicsItems is enabled
S: AUT stderr (49820018): INFO: SquishQtDeclarative: QML hierarchy filtering is enabled
S: AUT stderr (49820018): INFO: Loaded wrapper extension SquishDeclarativeExtension
S: AUT stderr (49820018): INFO: Loaded wrapper extension squishqtprintsupport
S: AUT stderr (49820018): INFO: Loaded wrapper extension SquishQtQuickExtension
S: AUT stderr (49820018): INFO: Loaded wrapper extension QGraphicsViewExt
S: AUT stderr (49820018): INFO: Loaded wrapper extension QTabWidgetExt
S: AUT stderr (49820018): INFO: Loaded wrapper extension QtDeclarativeWebViewExt
S: AUT stderr (49820018): INFO: Loaded wrapper extension openglgrabwidget
S: AUT stderr (49820018): INFO: Loading Qt Wrapper configuration from "/home/conjar/tools/squish/5.1.1/etc/qtwrapper.ini"
R: Runner::call: socket of context -1 is null
```

Answer (score 2):

This could be the indication of that the `squishserver` is not running and could not be started by the Squish IDE. Make sure you start it with `bin/squishserver` command from your Squish installation directory or configure the IDE to start it automatically from the "Preferences" dialog.

Comment: Tried that and Squish still gives the same error message. Other ideas? The same script and app works fine in Windows.